# IE7 on pressing "enter" key does not prevent default action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a form which contains:

```
<button class="submit">Submit</button>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$(".submit").click(function(e){
   var evt = e || window.event; // IE compatibility
   if(evt.preventDefault){  
     evt.preventDefault();  
   }else{  
      evt.returnValue = false;  
    evt.cancelBubble=true;  
  }
 //....ajax call 
});
```

So, I was wondering what am I doing wrong that in IE7 when I type search term and press enter it goes to my home page(action in `form ="/"`). Why it does not prevent IE7 from going to default action.

- is it because I am using button tag
- I also tried old way in form `onsubmit` call some function but it fails
- or is it because of ajax call?

Additional note:

- I have body and inside that body I have iframe and in that iframe I have form. So, I wonder is it because of iframe.

Comment: Try setting the action in the form to `"javascript:;"`

Comment: You might set the `button` attribute `type` literally (`button` maybe? If you want to cancel it altogether, always), and then `return false` and `e.stopPropagation()`? (Hazy on the IE7 specs at this point.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to handle that manually. The `e` in that scope is a [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and calling preventDefault() should be all you need to do. What might be happening is that the 'enter' button pressed event might not be triggering a 'click' event. Are you sure the event is raised at all? Try putting in an alert then doing the enter-button-press

Comment: @nbrooks....you are right when I put alert it does not alert as well...so can u give insight why event is not raised?

Comment: Side note: I think it's better to drop support for IE 7 and IE 6, so they can go away for good to save programmers' lives from these evil browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are preventing the default action of the button tag, which does not affect input triggered events, also note that jQuery Event object `preventDefault()` method is cross-browser, try this:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e){
  if (e.which == 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```